# CSS or JS - change background color of input when input is focused out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus, html-input

Is there any way to set a `background-color` on input text when it looses focus?

I'm trying in js but i would like to know if it's possible in css pure.

this seems not working

```
input{
 background-color:#fff !important;
}   
input:focus{
background-color:#333 !important;
}
//input:unfocused and has value{ ??? :) }

 $('input,textarea').on('focusout',function(e){
      if($(this).val().length){
       $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
      }
      });
```

thank you

Comment: CSS `!important` statement is not supported by jquery `.css()` method, remove it or use class

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you man, but still not working, cause i already have by default background-color: fff important; on input , just trying changing background if input has value and is focusout

Comment: the `:focus` pseudo-class will allow you to do it as a negative process. re-color when focused then back to normal when not.

Comment: @DevlshOne thanks but i i need 3 stetements backgrond : input, input:focus, input:focusout

Comment: @sbaaaang You could try `input:not(:focus)`

Comment: @DevlshOne won't work :( cause when i load page is already not_focus

Comment: Why are you using length in your code?

Comment: hey sorry i got the fix it was to remove some css now it works damn i'm sorry , thank you for your time, i voted to close this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS3 method would be, for example:

```
input[type=text]:focus{
    color:red;
}
```

See [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N9fwW/). Its a bit backward, you'd style the active, not the blurred selector.

To simulate blur, you can use `:not(:focus)`, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/MhmCg/)

Comment: this is for focus i need focusout :P

Comment: @sbaaaang, focus is the opposite. Style the normal (non :focus) selector for focusout. It does the same, but upside down in CSS

Comment: i need 3 stetements backgrond : input, input:focus, input:focusout

Comment: There is no focusout selector in CSS, this needs to be done in JS

Answer (score 1):

textarea and input are different selectors:

Do this with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('textarea').on('focusout',function(){ // When losing focus
            $(this).css('background','#FFF');
      });
      $('textarea').on('focus',function(){ // When focus
            $(this).css('background','#333');
      });
});
</script>
```

Or CSS:

```
textarea { background-color:#fff !important; }  
textarea:focus { background-color:#333 !important; }
```

Comment: hey sorry i got the fix it was to remove some css now it works damn i'm sorry , thank you for your time, i voted to close this